# YACC error "is untyped"

Tags: compiler-errors, yacc

I'm creating a YACC program that uses polish notation (prefix). It seems pretty simple to implement, but I'm getting an error that doesn't seem to make sense. The error is:

yacc: e - line 33 of "calculator.y", $1 ('-') is untyped

Here's the code for the expressions. The error occurs on the '-' rule. It stops there because I want to get this sorted out first:

```
exp:  NUMBER                  { $$ = $1; }
       | NAME                  { $$ = $1->value; }
       | NAME '=' exp         { $1->value = $3; $$ = $3; }
       | exp EQ exp      { $$ = $1 == $3; }
       | '-' exp exp        { $$ = $1 - $3; }
;
```

The weird thing is that it works fine when I try it with infix notation. I know this error usually occurs when tokens aren't properly typed, but they are since they work with infix notation. Any ideas why this would suddenly change with prefix?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    | '-' exp exp        { $$ = $1 - $3; }
```

Here you're trying to subtract the second expression from the `-` token, which is untyped, and doesn't make any sense.  You probably want

```
    | '-' exp exp        { $$ = $2 - $3; }
```

to subtract the second expression from the first expression...

Comment: Oh I see! I was misunderstanding the order of tokens. Thanks!